# Insert two responsive youtube video on the same row

Tags: css, youtube, embed, responsive

Hi everyone and thank you for taking the time to read this.
My problem is following. I'm trying to put 2 youtube videos on the same row and it's causing me some problem. So far, this what I have:
Html:

```
<div class="vimeo-wrapper">
<div class="vimeo-video-1 vimeo-standard">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hygokYbjbeY?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div class="vimeo-video-2 vimeo-standard">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/O1XotwR0_H0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<h2 id="cotizacion" style="color: white; border-radius: 8px; background-color: #008cba; text-align: center; display: center; font-size: 20px; padding: 14px 40px;"><strong>FILL OUT THIS FORM AND GET YOUR QUOTE WITHIN AN HOUR (DURING BUSINESS DAYS)</strong></h2>
```

css:

```
.postid-2916 .vimeo-wrapper {
    max-width: 980px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

.postid-2916 .vimeo-standard {
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    width: 47%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px;
}

.postid-2916 iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


.postid-2916 @media (max-width:767px) {

.postid-2916 .vimeo-standard {
        float: none;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}

.postid-2916 .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.postid-2916 .clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Somehow this is what I get [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Coq1N.jpg) it seems that my wrapper doesn't include my 2 videos. Any idea of what's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this code

```css
.vimeo-video-1,.vimeo-video-2
 {
    margin-right: 2%;border: 2px solid black;float:left;width:47%;
 }


.vimeo-wrapper
 {
   background-color: #008cba;
    width: 75%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 1% 6%;
 }
 .postid-2916 .vimeo-wrapper {
    max-width: 980px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

.postid-2916 .vimeo-standard {
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    width: 47%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px;
}

.postid-2916 iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


.postid-2916 @media (max-width:767px) {

.postid-2916 .vimeo-standard {
        float: none;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}

.postid-2916 .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.postid-2916 .clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.strong-custom-style{color: white;border-radius: 8px;text-align: center;font-size: 20px; padding: 14px 40px;display: block;clear: both;}
```

```html
<div class="vimeo-wrapper">
<div class="vimeo-video-1 vimeo-standard">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hygokYbjbeY?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div class="vimeo-video-2 vimeo-standard">
 <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/O1XotwR0_H0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<strong class="strong-custom-style">FILL OUT THIS FORM AND GET YOUR QUOTE WITHIN AN HOUR (DURING BUSINESS DAYS)</strong>
```

**This thing you need to add in media query width="560" height="315" .**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Code.
Html

```
<div class="vimeo-wrapper">
<div class="vimeo-video-1">
<iframe width="400" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hygokYbjbeY?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div class="vimeo-video-2">
<iframe width="400" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/O1XotwR0_H0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<h2 id="cotizacion" style="color: white; border-radius: 8px; background-color: #008cba; text-align: center; display: center; font-size: 20px; padding: 14px 40px;"><strong>FILL OUT THIS FORM AND GET YOUR QUOTE WITHIN AN HOUR (DURING BUSINESS DAYS)</strong></h2>
```

CSS

```
.vimeo-wrapper{

   width:100%


}

.vimeo-video-1{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}


.vimeo-video-2 {
  float:right;
  width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Replace This CSS  In Your Code

```
.postid-2916 > .vimeo-wrapper {

    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding-bottom:10px;

}

.vimeo-wrapper  >.vimeo-video-1  {
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    width: 50%;

}

.vimeo-wrapper  >.vimeo-video-2  {
    float: right;
    height: 300px;
    width: 50%;


}

.postid-2916 iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


.postid-2916 @media (max-width:767px) {

.postid-2916 .vimeo-standard {
        float: none;
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}

.postid-2916 .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.postid-2916 .clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```